# JQuery to highlight current menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a website and in that i have few menu links. I want to highlight the current menu items based on the url. Currently i have the following code in my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#menu a').each(function (index) {
            if (this.href.trim() == window.location.href)
                $(this).addClass("current");
        });
    });
```

Its working fine only when there is no query string present in the url. When i pass some query string into the url then this JQuery is not working.

Comment: `$(this).attr("href") == window.location.href` ?

Comment: Hi, @LeeTaylor i tried your suggestion, its showing me an error like **JavaScript runtime error: 'href' is undefined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `location.pathname` if you don't want the querystring.

This uses `filter()` to return just the relevant link(s)...

```
$("#menu a").filter(function (index) {
    return this.href.search(location.pathname) !== -1;
}).addClass("current");
```

Comment: Hi @Archer, I need to know how to do that

Comment: I've modified the answer.  Try that and let us know how you get on.